# Converting an unsigned long to 64-bit signed long in C

Tags: c, winapi, java-native-interface, type-conversion

I am trying to return a type jlong (defined in JNI as a signed 64-bit long value) from type DWORDLONG (defined in WIN32 as an unsigned 64-bit int).

Simply type casting:

```
DWORDLONG dwl = 1000000000000;
jlong n = (jlong) dwl;
```

changes the value since the operation is undefined.

How then do you convert an unsigned long to a signed long, maintaining the same numeric value it had before?

**Update**

It appears the issue was happening because of a pointer dereferencing error that slipped through my testing.  The cast was not altering the value.  Thanks to everyone who commented/answered, at least now I know this is a perfectly legal operation.

Comment: For positive numbers in the range of 64-bit signed integers (and 1E12 is well within range), the cast shown should work (but it would be more reliable if you added an LL or equivalent suffix to the value).  If it doesn't, there could be a mismatch in your expectations (something isn't 64-bit which you thought was a 64-bit value) or there could be a bug in the compiler.  I'm not sure whether there are many other choices. How do you know the value is changing?  Are you printing it in the C code, or are you waiting until the Java code gets hold of it? Have you printed `dwl` before the conversion?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use `jlong`?

Comment: `jint` isn't defined as 64-bits.  It's defined as 32 bits: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html  Do you mean `jlong` instead?

Comment: My apologies. I meant jlong. I dont know why I typed jint.

Comment: And yes I have tested the value in both C and Java. The changed value shows up in both.

Comment: Shouldn't `1000000000000` be `1000000000000LL`?

Comment: 1000000000 is simply an example number. The actual DWORDLONG is the amount of memory available or total on the system in bytes. So it will be somewhat bigger.

Comment: 'changes the value since the operation is undefined' is meaningless. If the operation was undefined the code wouldn't compile.

Comment: Maybe "Implementation-specific" would have been better wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you reach the conclusion that the cast changes the value?

The cast constitutes undefined behavior only if the cast value overflows the signed target type (64-bit integer), which should not occur for either 1000000000000 or "the amount of memory available" (and the pathological cases be protected against at run-time using `if (dwl > JLONG_MAX) raise_error()`). My guess is that you misinterpreted the test; the constant 1000000000000 overflowed the **32-bit** integer at compile-time and got compiled as -727379968. It wasn't the cast that changed the value, the value was corrupt to begin with.

As already suggested in the comments, change 1000000000000 to 1000000000000LL in your test program and the problem will disappear.

Comment: The problem occurs casting DWORDLONG to jlong. The whole jint casting thing was simply an error when I typed the question.

Comment: @ghostsoldier23 How have you demonstrated that the problem occurs when casting `DWORDLONG` to `jlong`? Since `DWORDLONG` is an unsigned 64-bit integer and `jlong` is a signed 64-bit integer, casting from `DWORDLONG` to `jlong` will work fine for all values smaller than 2**63. Based on currently available data, it looks like the overflow of the 1000000000000 constant in your test program led you to a false conclusion that the cast fails. (And this has nothing to do with the `jint` typo.)

Comment: I did find a dereferencing error for one of the DWORDLONG values. That may have had an effect. I will check the JNI output again when I am able and post the results.

Comment: Alright turns out it was the dereferencing error that screwed everything up, not the cast, which my testing hadn't shown (probably the placement of the test variable before the pointer assignment?).  So that problem is solved.  Now, if I was trying to cast it to a 32-bit signed int (not overflow), would it still work?

Comment: @ghostsoldier23 Yes, it would still work if there is no overflow. C has supported this since the beginning and this is widely used in system APIs such as stdio `getchar()`, where you are expected to routinely cast its `int` result to `char`, after having checked for the `EOF` special value.